# C# simpler run time generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there a way to invoke a generic function with a type known only at run time?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
    static  void bar()
    {
        object b = 6;
        string c = foo<typeof(b)>();
    }

    static  string foo<T>()
    {
       return typeof (T).Name;
    }
```

Basically I want to decide on the type parameter only at run time, but the function I'm calling depends on the type parameter.

Also I know this can be done with reflections... but it's not the nicest solution to the problem...

---

I'm sort of looking for dynamic features in C#...

---

I'm writhing a bridge between two classes the first one is basically a big tree with different types of of objects (composite by interface) the other is a sort of a "super visitor".
the supper visitor accepts key-value dictioneries that map types to object it looks like:
     dic.Add(object value)

and T is not necessarily the type of the value... a lot of times it isn't...
I know it's written poorly, but i can't fix it...
I can work around it, but only at runtime...

I already did it with reflections, but if there's a better way to do it without them i would be happy to learn...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but you can get `dynamic` to do the reflection work for you by something like,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = 6;
        var t = (dynamic)new T();
        var n = t.Foo(b);
    }

    class T
    {
        public string Foo<T>(T a)
        {
            return typeof(T).Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the dynamic call will extract the type of `b` and use it as a type parameter for `Foo()`.

Comment: +1 I didnt find a way to do that using dynamics.
the thing is, im not passing a paramater of type T to my foo function... is there a way to get around that with dynamic?

Comment: No. You would need reflection if you don't actually pass b as a parameter. If you provide more details about what you are really trying to do it would be easier to provide you with a solution. The above is much easier to do as typeof(b).Name so obviously that is not really what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` keyword if you're using .NET 4. In a word, the type of the variable will be resolved at run time so it is a super generic type ;) You can read a article [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx) or read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: typeof() is an operator, returning a System.Type , it has a property called "Name"... and it's just an example demonstrating that i want to accept the correct type at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

Saly refelction is THE solution to the problem, whether it is nice or not is irrelevant here. It is the runtime designed mechanism to achieve exactly this. As there is no parameter or generics to use as input, this is the only way to do it - it is also senseless. As in: your example is bad. Because in the example the type is hardcoded.

If the method where b exists has b as generic parameter, the type is available for passing to foo. If not - reflection is THE way to go, albeit the syntax looks clumsy. Only one time, though.

Comment: of course i dont really know the type of b at run time... that's why I'm casting the int to object... 
I think reflections are a very bad solution here... ugly and unnecessary... the type for a generic function, is just another sort of parameter, and is handled accordingly by the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This I believe is the only way:

```
 var foo =  typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(typeof (bar));
```

Comment: Yes, in the question it is, you are right.  I knocked up a quick test in which Foo<T> was a class, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a class which takes a type parameter at run time which can be used in the methods in that class.

```
public class GenericClass<T>()
{
    ICommonInterface TheObject;

    public GenericClass(T theObject)
    {
         TheObject = theObject;
    }


    public string GetName()
    {
        return TheObject.Name;
    }
}
```

But this is only really useful if the Types being passed in share interfaces so have common properties between them. In your example it seems that relection is the answer as depending on the type you want to access specific properties.

Comment: I dont control the type of the objects i receive,  nor the generic function im calling. and a common interface wont help... I used the System.Type.Name, to demonstrate the generic class im calling actually does something with the type i pass to it.